# Where does the sound we hear from short circuits come from?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, acoustics, frequency, short-circuits

Title is self explanatory.

Whenever I see or watch a short circuit happening, there is always a humming/buzzing sound going on (e.g., the sounds we hear from [this short circuit compilation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOT8jx4jEzM)).

Where is this sound originated?

Comment: Well, there is a release of energy that is heating things up to begin with. Compare with, for example, YouTube videos of arc flashes (note - some of those may be distressing to watch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The humming in most cases comes from the source being AC. Compare the frequency of the humming with a 100 or [120 Hz Tone](https://youtu.be/SVYFpfJBzWA) (depending on where you are) and you will find them to be similar. The tone frequency is double that of the current, because there are two zeros and two maxima in one period of the sine wave.

So the current increases and decreases with 100-120 Hz, which changes - among other things - the plasma at the same frequency, generating a sound. Of course there are also contributions from the mayham it causes to the structures around it, some of which are also periodic with the same frequency. This yields quite a wide range of sound patterns a short can produce.